# Filtrar por clase sin usar stream al leer un array de objetos con expresiones lambda de Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

Estoy probando las expresiones Lambda de Java 8.

En mi código creo una lista de objetos que pueden ser del tipo `Person` o del tipo `Employee`.

La clase `Employee` extiende de `Person` y yo quiero, mediante una expresión lambda mostrar la información mediante el método `showData` **únicamente de los objetos de la lista que sean del tipo `Employee`**.

De esta forma me funciona:

```
    lstPersons.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof Employee)
        .forEach(theEmployee -> theEmployee.showData()); 
    }
```

Pero aquí usa `stream` <s>y usa `map`</s>.

Dado que yo puedo leer todos los objetos así:

```
    lstPersons.forEach(item -> item.showData());
```

**¿No hay otra forma más simple de aplicar el filtro, sin tener que usar `stream` <s>y `map`</s>?**

Aquí pueden ver una <kbd>**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RVLAD50041)**</kbd> del código que estoy probando.

Comment: creo que no se puede filtrar sin usar stream, por que la clase stream sirve para admitir operaciones de estilo funcional en flujos de elementos, como las  transformaciones map-reducir en colecciones.

Comment: @x-rw ahora probé a quitarle la parte del `map` y me funciona bien: `lstPersons.stream().filter(item -> item instanceof Employee)
        .forEach(theEmployee -> theEmployee.showData()); 
    }` ... antes no logré hacerlo sin pasar por el `map`, no sé por qué.  Lo de filtrar sin `stream` habría que confirmarlo.

Comment: Una forma de utilizar un equivalente al filtro, sería de esta forma..
`System.out.println("Pasando filtro");
        lstPersons.forEach((emp) -> {
            if (emp instanceof Employee) {
                emp.showData();
            }
        });` Todo esto dentro del método foreach perteneciente a Iterable, el cual podemos utilizarlo con List

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que sigas a los [principios de la programación orientada a objetos](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/java/tutorials/j-introtojava1/index.html), usando encapsulación de propiedades, y [separando las clases en distintos archivos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html),de la siguiente manera:

## Clase Persona:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int idNumber;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int idNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(int idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    public void showData() {
        String s = String.format("Nombre: %s%nApellido :%s%nID: %s%n%n", firstName, lastName, idNumber);
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

## Clase Empleado:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    private String areaName;
    private double amountSalary;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int idNumber, String areaName, Double amountSalary) {
        super(firstName, lastName, idNumber);
        this.areaName = areaName;
        this.amountSalary = amountSalary;

    }

    public String getAreaName() {
        return areaName;
    }

    public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
        this.areaName = areaName;
    }

    public double getAmountSalary() {
        return amountSalary;
    }

    public void setAmountSalary(double amountSalary) {
        this.amountSalary = amountSalary;
    }

    @Override
    public void showData() {
        String s = String.format("Nombre: %s%nApellido :%s%nID: %s%nÁrea :%s%nSalario :%.2f%n%n", getFirstName(),
                getLastName(), getIdNumber(), areaName, amountSalary);
        System.out.print(s);

    }
}
```

## Clase Rextester:

Aquí, podemos usar [Predicado](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/expresiones-lambda-con-java-8/#034), que es una interfaz funcional que define una condición booleana (verdadero o falso), por ejemplo, que la clase persona tenga un id determinado, que los elementos sean de la clase empleado o persona solamente, y cualquier regla de negocio que necesites.

Ahora, podemos encapsular un método que al recibir una lista de personas, aplique un determinado [tester](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.function/Predicate/1020__Predicate.test.htm) (predicado) para imprimir la lista:

```
public static void printPersonWithPredicate(List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> tester) {
        for (Person p : persons) {
            if (tester.test(p)) { //Si pasa el test
                p.showData(); //imprime los datos
            }
        }
    }
```

Finalmente podemos usarla para imrpimir según la condición buscada:

```
printPersonWithPredicate(lstPersons, p -> p.getClass() == Employee.class);
```

Te dejaré la clase completa con la que probe para que no tengas problemas, además probé imprimiendo solo Personas:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Rextester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final List<Person> lstPersons = new ArrayList<>();
        lstPersons.add(new Employee("Empleado1", "Ap1", 123456, "Informática", 2000.50));
        lstPersons.add(new Person("Persona1", "Apellido1", 1));
        lstPersons.add(new Employee("Empleado2", "Ap2", 123457, "Contabilidad", 1900.00));
        lstPersons.add(new Person("Persona2", "Apellido2", 2));
        lstPersons.add(new Person("Persona3", "Apellido3", 3));

        /* Leer todas las Personas */
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", "TODAS LAS PERSONAS:");
        lstPersons.forEach(item -> item.showData());

        /* Leer los Empleados */
        System.out.printf("%n%s%n%n", "SOLAMENTE LOS EMPLEADOS:");

        printPersonWithPredicate(lstPersons, p -> p.getClass() == Employee.class);

        /* Leer las personas */
        System.out.printf("%n%s%n%n", "SOLAMENTE LAS PERSONAS:");

        printPersonWithPredicate(lstPersons, p -> p.getClass() == Person.class);

    }

    public static void printPersonWithPredicate(List<Person> persons, Predicate<Person> tester) {
        for (Person p : persons) {
            if (tester.test(p)) {
                p.showData();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Output:

Para finalizar, la salida sería la siguiente:

```
TODAS LAS PERSONAS:

Nombre: Empleado1
Apellido :Ap1
ID: 123456
Área :Informática
Salario :2000.50

Nombre: Persona1
Apellido :Apellido1
ID: 1

Nombre: Empleado2
Apellido :Ap2
ID: 123457
Área :Contabilidad
Salario :1900.00

Nombre: Persona2
Apellido :Apellido2
ID: 2

Nombre: Persona3
Apellido :Apellido3
ID: 3


SOLAMENTE LOS EMPLEADOS:

Nombre: Empleado1
Apellido :Ap1
ID: 123456
Área :Informática
Salario :2000.50

Nombre: Empleado2
Apellido :Ap2
ID: 123457
Área :Contabilidad
Salario :1900.00


SOLAMENTE LAS PERSONAS:

Nombre: Persona1
Apellido :Apellido1
ID: 1

Nombre: Persona2
Apellido :Apellido2
ID: 2

Nombre: Persona3
Apellido :Apellido3
ID: 3
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero no veo por qué sería mejor dejar de usar streams para usar esta solución (mucho más código para una operación sencilla). Salvo que haya algún impedimento técnico (versión de java), yo usaría streams.

Comment: Claramente, pero la pregunta tiene esa restricción

Comment: Sí, sí, era más un comentario para A. Cedano

Comment: Gracias. Las clases están mezcladas porque es una restricción de Rextester y quería mostrar un ejemplo funcional. Yo preguntaba por una solución basada en Lambda, pero sin tener que pasar por `map` y por `stream`.  Lo primero lo solucioné haciendo unas pruebas (pude evitar el `map`, al principio no me funcionaba sin `map` no sé por qué... pero no el `stream`). Al parecer [`stream` es obligatorio para filtrar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178585/filtrar-por-clase-sin-usar-stream-al-leer-un-array-de-objetos-con-expresiones-la#comment335346_178585). Con esto respondo también a @pablo

Comment: Entiendo. De igual modo está solución usa solo lambda